# inputBox or addPanel

Tags: google-apps-script

after running a couple of scripts I realized that some of my scripts are not very practical. I have a script that asks four times with inputBoxes four different variables. I was thinking if it's possible to just have like a big panel with boxes where all these data can be input and then once it's done just click submit and on that way all information is stored on their variables.. Is it possible or anyone has a clue on how to do it??

```
  function dashboards(){
 var name = Browser.inputBox("Enter your name:");
 var nstats1 = Browser.inputBox("Enter your last name:");
 var namedash = Browser.inputBox("Enter your DOB");
 var log = Browser.inputBox("Enter your deparmtent");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible ways to do this, the easiest are certainly the [UI service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp) and the [GUI builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder).

I' suggest you have a look at this documentation... you'll find a lot of examples here and around.

[Here is a rough example using the GUI Builder](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AnqSFd3iikE3dHkyMkhYY01iV19nUm0zaGJwUEg2X0E#gid=0), you'll see its pretty simple to use and/or customise to your needs...

Comment: Thank you Serge! I am already reading to get a better idea :) .